# Clang AST Libtooling: How to print Array identifier on AST Matching

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, libtooling, clang-ast-matchers

My code that I tried is below:

```
if(const ArraySubscriptExpr *array = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<ArraySubscriptExpr>("array"))
    {
        llvm::outs() << array->getBase() <<'\n';
    }
```

*getBase()* should print the array identifier, but it is printing the address, e.g. *0x559f7da7e838*. How can I print the array name/identifier?
For example, in the case of *arr[i] = 40;*
I want to print *arr*

Answer (score 1):

getBase returns a pointer to the base expression, so that is why the address is being printed. The AST for arr[i] is:

```
| |-ArraySubscriptExpr 0xc04c608 <col:3, col:8> 'double' lvalue
| | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0xc04c5d8 <col:3> 'double *' <LValueToRValue>
| | | `-DeclRefExpr 0xc04c598 <col:3> 'double *' lvalue Var 0xc04c480 'arr' 'double *'
| | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0xc04c5f0 <col:7> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
| |   `-DeclRefExpr 0xc04c5b8 <col:7> 'int' lvalue Var 0xc04c518 'i' 'int'
```

As can be seen, the name of the array appears in the children of the ImplicitCastExpr node which is children of ArraySubscriptExpr. This worked for me:

```
if (auto *array  = dyn_cast<ArraySubscriptExpr>(st)) {
    if (auto *cast = dyn_cast<ImplicitCastExpr>(array->getBase())) {
        if (auto *decl = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(cast->getSubExpr())) {
            cout << decl->getNameInfo().getAsString() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```